# Is there a JS library for doing LQL link filtering that supports math operands also?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, syntax

EDIT: For additional context into the question, I'm writing a web app in JS that displays an array of JS objects. The app has users that log in. I want each user to be able to create and save custom list filters that can be reused later. Those list filters can be authored by any method, including using a scripting language. Hence, I'm trying to figure out a way to save custom list filter scripts per user. That's why I've been researching LQL (and later today, JMESPath).

Imagine I have an array of JS objects (call them humans) that have the following properties:

```
{
  id: 'id00', // string
  height: 72, // integer, in centimeters
  weight: 54, // integer, in kilograms
  eye_color: 'blue', // string
}
```

In JS, I can write the following code:

```
arrayOfHumans.filter(human => {
  return human.height > (3 * human.weight / 4)
});
```

I want to be able to perform the above filter by typing it into an `<input>` field in a web app. I have come across LQL/Lucene ([reference NPM package, liqe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/liqe)) which let's me write things like:

```
# 2 examples using comparators with height (=, >, >=, <, <=)
height:=100
height:>100

# conditional example
name:foo AND height:=100
```

However, I have been unable to find something (ideally as an npm package) that lets me do something more complex like my JS filter example (multiple parameters and math operators).

I'm struggling to define exactly what I'm looking for. Searches for parsers with math operators and multiple parameter support has not yielded anything. I feel like I'm missing something, which is why I'm posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Even if you find such a package, you'll always have to implement your own logic and here in your use case using a library or not, will not affect performance.

Comment: @Hatana See my EDIT at the top for more context. Am I making sense?